# Where can I find Druid broker/coordinator configuration details?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-superset, druid

I'm working on the Hontonworks platform with Druid and Superset.

An architect has configured the connection to the Druid cluster on Superset.
That works, but I would like to understand where I can find all this information.

To declare a Druid cluster on Superset, I have to set parameters. The configuration that works looks like:

```
 - Coordinator Host : <URL of the cluster Druid>
 - Coordinator Port : 8081
 - Coordinator Endpoint : druid/coordinator/v1
 - Broker Host : <URL of the cluster Druid>
 - Broker Port : 8888
 - Broker Endpoint : druid/v2
```

Does anyone know where can I find all this information?